# Why can't I sort this PowerBI chart?

Tags: powerbi

I have charts I want to sort descending. I've read there's a "more options" option if you click on the chart, which should give you ability to sort.

In chart below, there is no sorting option:

[image]

Here is the field the chart is based on (it's a single field):

[image]

And here's the way I set up the chart:

[image]

I click 'more options' and yet see no option to sort. Who knew such a simple task could be that difficult in PowerBI.

Comment: Can you share a snapshot of your axis,value and legend details

Comment: sorry, but what do you want to sort???

Comment: the chart, descending order.  I have multiple charts I want to sort, this is one example.  None are letting me sort.

Comment: Sort by WHAT? Do you want to re-arrange the order of the bars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess at this point is that you are using two different fields for Male and Female numbers. If this is the case, you won't get the sorting option since the values are coming from two different fields. If you simply want to interchange the position, you can do so in the values section. If this is not the case, please provide further details, so that we can look into it further.

Edit:

I don't think there is a sorting option without having a value in Axis. However, you can adjust the Inner Padding of the Y-axis (in the formatting pane), to get the visual you are looking for. Setting inner padding to 0% will remove all the gap between the two bars. Also, you can do the sorting now, since there is a value in the Axis box.

Note: If you want different colors, add the field in legend as well.

Comment: Nope, it's one field.  I've edited the question to include more detail about the field itself and the way I set up the chart.  The only way I can get "sort" option is if I drag the column over the 'axis' section - which I don't want to do since it totally messes up my chart.  I want the chart to look as is, just sorted.... thanks.

Comment: ... or just change the chart type. see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a clustered bar chart. The columns are arranged alphabetically and can't be changed.

If you want to sort the bars by their values, use a regular stacked bar chart and put the "demo_female" in the Axis, not the Legend.

[image]